# Is it possible to write Windows 8 drivers without Visual Studio professional?

Tags: wdk

The standard methodology for performing Windows 8 DDK work is to load Visual studio
professional, then Windows DDK 8. After that you can use msbuild to avoid using VS
to build drivers.

I would like to know if it is possible to avoid loading a paid version of Visual Studio
for freeware work. Previously you could do this by using just the DDK (DDK 7 or earlier).
However, now I don't see a way to develop drivers using only freeware components.

Thanks,

Scott Moore

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, now WDK requires MSVC 2012 installed before : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852362#_System_Requirements. Also now WDK don`t include toolset (compiler, linker, etc) and i think there are no way to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with "WDK 8.1 Update" the WDK works also with VS Express 2013 (**free**). I think the worst limitation of Express edition it's the lack of PREfast.